# Macro Copy/Paste Excel Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the Macro code to copy and paste a list of values from Input, where Records are entered to Completed, the headers are the same.

```
Sub a()
Sheets("ITM").Range("A1:AD1000").Copy
Sheets("ISP").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlValues
End Sub
```

This is working for the Copy and paste, however I need to adjust it to take into account existing filled fields, so that older Completed Records do not get over written.

Sample Data:

ITM:

User enters data

```
Header A   - Header B   -  Header C
  Ex          BY              TY
```

ISP

This has a record of all previous data that were entered, and macro will add the latest ISP entered data to next available row.

```
Request #        Header A    -      Header B    -  Header C
   1               XY                  TY              ER
   2               QW                  WE              EW
   3               EX                  BY              TY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Paste Special, values` operation can be substituted with a direct transfer which does not involve the clipboard and is typically a little faster. By *'take into account existing filled fields'*, I will take it to mean that you want to put new information into the first blank row on the **ISP** worksheet and not overwrite previous records.

```
Sub a()
    With Sheets("ITM").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
        With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 30)
            Sheets("ISP").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp) _
              .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count) = .Value
            Sheets("ISP").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Resize(.Rows.Count + 1, 1) _
              .DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Step:=1
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

You didn't mention any column header labels so I did not account for them. If you have column header labels that you do not wish to bring across each time, the data range can be offset 1 row down.

Comment: I may have gotten my question a little wrong, I meant that ISP would be for example a record sheet, now these will have in Column A, Completed # 1, where A will contain 1, 2, 3, 4. then for A1, it will contain values in columns B, c, d, e, f, etc. So in theory in ISP I would add a new record, use macro which would copy values from ISP and enter it with the headers, which are located across the first row, and the values will be entered in a new empty row without effecting older ones.Thank you

Comment: @user1860175 - This question really needs sample data together with expected results in order to completely understand the process.

Comment: Added a rough sample.

Comment: @user1860175 -  While that isn't 1000 rows × 30 columns, it does provide a better idea of what is actually going on. Please see the modified sub above.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for this. It is working, however one issue, its not inserting into a new row, e.g. if I clear ISP and add new values, using the rough sample, I replace EX BY TY, with ER, TR, BR, it will replace the existing values in that position. where as I want it too insert it in a new row. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: @user1860175 - do you have numbers in the ISP worksheet's column A as per your sample?

Comment: Its working now, even though it skips 1 and pastes onto 2, 3, 4, lol, so I've started from 0 as blank, thanks again. Also if anyone else is using this, make sure your column of numbers starts with just one number to begin with if its empty as Jeeped's code automatically adds further numbers, awesome work, thanks again Jeeped.

Comment: Quick comment if you read this, chaning "  With .Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 30)" Offset to 34, would start it at 34 correct? I've done that and to read downwards I've had to change Rows.Count to -100, 60. Is that right?

Comment: @user1860175 - No, the *30* represents *30 columns wide* in the `.Resize`. Your original question referred to `Range("A1:AD1000")` which is 30 columns wide. `.Offset(1, 0)` moves the referenced data down one row to avoid copying the header. The `.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 30)` shortens the new offset range by one row while maintaining the 30 column width.

Comment: So how come when I change the offset to 34 to start from row 34, it only copys one row of data, and so I have to change the Rows.Count to -100 in order to count 100 rows?

Comment: Your description(s) do(es) not adequately illustrate the new situation. I would suggest starting a new question where you can expand on the description and show sample data together with the results that you are expecting to return. Alternately, edit this question to include an addendum with the above suggested description, sample data and expected results. The comment section of an answer is inadequate for this and I do not believe that you have the necessary rep points for a chat.